# Is mod_auth_basic transmitted as cleartext under https?

Tags: apache, security, authentication, ssl, https

I'm using `mod_auth_basic` to restrict access to an SSL folder, is the password transmitted as cleartext?

Do I need to use `mod_auth_digest`?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "as cleartext". In the HTTP basic authentication exchange, passwords are sent as cleartext (encoded as base64). But the whole exchange is tunneled through the encrypted SSL connection, so you can't see them by observing the traffic. But the server on the other end of the exchange can totally see the passwords. At which points do you need the password to not be cleartext?

Comment: @AndrewJanke, thanks, I want to protect (encrypt password and data) from man in the middle

Comment: The HTTPS/SSL connection takes care of that then. All the in-flight data, including the password for basic auth, is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, seems an answer to me ;)

Comment: Okay, makin' it an answer then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "as cleartext". In the HTTP basic authentication exchange, passwords are sent as cleartext (encoded as base64). But the whole exchange is tunneled through the encrypted SSL connection, so you can't see them by observing the traffic. (Unless you've successfully compromised the SSL connection itself and can see all the traffic.) When doing basic auth through HTTPS/SSL, the server at the other end can still see your passwords as cleartext, but it's sufficient to protect against man-in-the-middle eavesdropping.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using mod_auth_basic to restrict access to an SSL folder, is the password transmitted as cleartext?

Yes. Its transmitted in the clear *within* the SSL/TLS tunnel.

> Do I need to use mod_auth_digest?

That's usually a problem, too.

---

The problem is that anyone that answers with a certificate is accepted. More correctly, the tunnel lacks "channel binding", where app authentication is part of the channel setup. So if someone intercepts the communication (i.e., proxy) or impersonates the up the server (phishing), then you send him/her `password` or `MD5(password)`.

Its better to use a SSL/TLS protocol like TLS-SRP or TLS-PSK. Each use shared secrets like passwords, and each properly bind the channel. And both don't do dumb things like put the password on the wire in the plain text.

You can read more about these problems and solutions in Peter Gutmann's [Enginerring Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf).

Comment: "*The problem is that anyone that answers with a certificate is accepted*": not really, a properly configured client will still check the certificate (including host name) *before* any HTTP communication happens (so before the password is sent).